# paypal sandbox: auto return not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

breaking our heads over how to get autoreturn to work in sandbox.

1. **We have enabled the auto return feature in the sandbox account
   associated with the APP we use:**

[image]

**2. We have entered the return URL in developer.paypal.com in the APPs settings:**

[image]

**3. And still. We are not returned back to our URL provided:**
[image]

**note also that we have waited several hours between changing something and testing it as instructed. Any help highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer found. according to paypal support auto-return does not work with the paypal invoicing API, which we use, just express checkout etc.

Comment: how to disable Invoicing API

Answer (score 1):

Try turning Payment Data Transfer on in Sandbox account (next section down in Website Payment Preferences).

Comment: Thanks but dosn't help. Also it says (optional).

Comment: Hmm. I have this working with Auto Return and PDT on. I'm also sending the return URL with each transaction, although I don't think that should be required.

Comment: yeah, totally strange. done everything in accordance with any guide or post we could find.

Comment: It might have to do with whether the buyer is using a PayPal account or credit card option. Auto Return might only work with payment from PayPal account.

Comment: yeah. we test with both.